# How to integrate without namespace clash?

Tags: python

I am writing some code to calculate the integral of (1+cos(pi * x))^2 between -1 and 1, but when I use the following code I get a clash with my packages. How would I redefine things to make sure I don't clash?

```
    import numpy as np
    import sympy as sp
    from sympy import Symbol

    x = Symbol('x')
    integral = sp.integrate((1 + np,cos(np.pi * x))**2, (x, -1, 1))
```

It is returning the error "'Mul' object has no attribute 'cos'". How can I fix this? I can't see how to fix it as I need both the numpy and sympy packages.

Comment: first of all, fix the typo at `np,cos` to `np.cos`. Also, `np` is defined somewhere as a `Mul` object, i.e. you `import` it as numpy, but eventually create a variable with the same name `np`. Make sure you don't do that